# Change path that is send from xdebug to PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

We deploy our develop branch to a remote server every day with jenkins and capifony. We keep several deployments and a symlink points to the current dev release. `/var/www/dev/current -> /var/www/dev/release/<DATE>`.
On my local computer I use PhpStorm that is listening to xdebug via ssh tunnel to the server. I work on a local copy and upload the changes to the dev server.

The server path mapping for xdebug in PhpStorm is pointing to `/var/www/dev/release/<DATE>` because xdebug sends it that way.

Is it possible to replace `release/<DATE>` with `current` so I don't need to change the server path mapping in PhpStorm every day?

Comment: Those paths are produced by xdebug (or more likely PHP itself -- does not really matter) and sent to debug client (PhpStorm in our case) by xdebug -- just as you described. Unfortunately there is no setting in xdebug that would allow such replacement. If you wish you may try some sort of proxy maybe and dynamically replace paths there (if such replacement is possible at all, of course). But the "easiest" would be to build xdebug from sources that you would alter in advance to allow such replacement.

Comment: @LazyOne would that not be a 'good thing' for PhpStorm to implement as a feature since in all cases it receives via a port ... ie like a 'rewrite' rule depending on the deployment target ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg PhpStorm's Issue Tracker where you can leave your feature request is located here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI